# Razor Page not loading properly sometimes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, razor

I have an ASP .NET MVC 4 application which has been deployed on IIS 6. The first page that is rendered when user hits the URL is the login page which is a simple Razor page with a form for login and a some javascript.

It actually looks like this -

[image]

But sometimes, I'm guessing when the server is very busy with many requests, it looks like this -

[image]

The images are not rendered properly, or sometimes I can see raw HTML or JavaScript in the page etc. After I refresh the page a few times, it looks like it should.

How can I fix this? Is there any way by which I can show the page contents only when everything has been rendered to the client by the server?

PS: The users use IE 8 and above.

Comment: You should give us some code so we may hopefully identify the problem you're having. But from what I see from the images, the page is only rendered correctly when it is localhost, it is not when it's in IIS .

Comment: It is also rendered correctly from IIS most of the times. This occurs only sometimes.

Comment: Does this happen to other applications hosted on the IIS too?

Comment: please check console if there is problem in loading resources